# ReactJS not binding via map to state values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm working with an MVC5 project and running into an issue with React not binding an array. I had this working in an MVC Core project, but had to "regress" back to the old structure. Biggest change seemed to be in the controller, changing from JsonResult (Core MVC) to Json (MVC5) for the return type on the ajax call.

Here's the output from Chrome Developer Tools:
(removed due to lack of reputation points)

And, my code for my .jsx file:

```
var LineItem = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="gridItem">
                <div className="lessLineHeight smallFont">
                    <div className='section group'>
                        <div className="col span_1_of_2" id={this.props.ordHeaderId}>
                            <text>{this.props.code}</text>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col span_1_of_2 text-right'>
                            <i className={this.props.apptIconString} aria-hidden='true'></i>
                            <i className={this.props.highValueIconString}></i>
                            <i className={this.props.hazmatIconString}></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='section group'>
                        <div className='col span_6_of_10'>
                            <text title='Trading Partner - Client'>{this.props.tradingPartnerName}</text>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col span_4_of_10 text-right'>
                            <text className='overflowElip' title='Account Manager'>{this.props.accountManager}</text>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='section group'>
                        <div className='col span_1_of_2'>
                            <text title={"Origin: " + this.props.originAddress + "; " + this.props.origContact}>{this.props.originAddress}</text>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col span_1_of_2 text-right'>
                            <text title={"Destination:" + this.props.destinationAddress + "; " + this.props.destContact}>{this.props.destinationCity}</text>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='section group'>
                        <div className='col span_1_of_3'>${this.props.freightValue}</div>
                        <div className='col span_1_of_3 text-center'>
                            <a title='Promote Order to Load'>To Load</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col span_1_of_3 text-right' id={'datePlanned' + this.props.ordHeaderId}>
                            <text title='Pickup Date'>{this.props.dateCreated}</text>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ItemList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { items: [] };
    },
    loadData: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ items: data });
                console.log(this.state.items);
                $("#column1").find(".gridItem:odd").css({ "background-color": "#ddd" }).end().find(".gridItem:even").css({ "background-color": "#fff" });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadData();
        /*window.setInterval(this.loadData, this.props.pollInterval);*/
    },
    render: function () {
        if (this.state.items) {
            console.log("State has items.");
            var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (foo) {
                return (
                        <LineItem key={foo.ordHeaderId}
                                  accountManager={foo.accountManager}
        apptIconString={foo.apptIconString}
        commodityDescription={foo.commodityDescription}
        commodityId={foo.commodityId}
        dateCreated={foo.dateCreated}
        deliveryAppt={foo.deliveryAppt}
        destContact={foo.destContact}
        destinationAddress={foo.destinationAddress}
        destinationAddressName={foo.destinationAddressName}
        destinationCity={foo.destinationCity}
        earlyDeliveryTime={foo.earlyDeliveryTime}
        earlyPickupTime={foo.earlyPickupTime}
        equipmentName={foo.equipmentName}
        freightValue={foo.freightValue}
        handlingUnits={foo.handlingUnits}
        hazmatIconString={foo.hazmatIconString}
        highValueIconString={foo.highValueIconString}
        isHazmat={foo.isHazmat}
        isHighValue={foo.isHighValue}
        lateDeliveryTime={foo.lateDeliveryTime}
        latePickupTime={foo.latePickupTime}
        loadId={foo.loadId}
        loadNum={foo.loadNum}
        loadTmsStatus={foo.loadTmsStatus}
        ordHeaderId={foo.ordHeaderId}
        ordNum={foo.ordNum}
        orderType={foo.orderType}
        origContact={foo.originContact}
        originAddress={foo.originAddress}
        originAddressName={foo.originAddressName}
        originationCity={foo.originationCity}
        pickupAppt={foo.pickupAppt}
        pieces={foo.pieces}
        plannedEnd={foo.plannedEnd}
        plannedStart={foo.plannedStart}
        requiredTemp={foo.requiredTemp}
        specialInstructions={foo.specialInstructions}
        targetCost={foo.targetCost}
        teamId={foo.teamId}
        tempControlled={foo.tempControlled}
        tradingPartnerNameCNum={foo.tradingPartnerNameCNum}
        tradingPartnerName={foo.tradingPartnerNameClient}
        transportMode={foo.transportMode}
        user3gIdBookedBy={foo.user3gIdBookedBy}
        user3gIdCreatedBy={foo.user3gIdCreatedBy}
        weight={foo.weight} />
                );
            });
            return (
                <div className="itemList">
                    {itemNodes}
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ItemList url="/DispatchBoard/getColumn1Data" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('column1')
);
```

As you can see from the image, the render: in the loadData function sees the items coming back from the ajax call, and then sets them to state, but when it comes time to map them, it does nothing.

Any ideas on what I'm not seeing?

**EDIT**

Here's a screen show showing the 'undefined' value(s) in one of the LineItems after failing to map properly. [undefined values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TgRO.png)

**EDIT #2**

Here's a screenshot showing that the objects are hydrated and not being parsed. [object present, not parsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2cfK.png)

Comment: At line `<LineItem key={foo.ordHeaderId}` maybe `ordHeaderId` is same for all the items, you can try changing `var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (foo) {` to `var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (foo, index) {` and then change `<LineItem key={foo.ordHeaderId}` to `<LineItem key={index}`

Comment: Well, that advice did remove the "index" error, but didn't do anything to resolve the fact that none of the values in the JSON array are being hydrated into the LineItems. Also, the responder's advice will be moot once I can get the LineItems hydrated as OrdHeaderId is the primary key (unique) in the database.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that issue, after `var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (foo, index) {` add `console.log('item',foo)` and see whats being logged into the console.. and also put the log somewhere for us to see.

Comment: I meant the log you see in the `developer console` and not in `react` tab.. as i cannot say much before actually seeing the data and its structure.

Comment: It looks from the console that it's not parsing anything. Gets into it fine, and then just says 'these are not the droids you're looking for'.

Comment: If its not parsing anything, how will it be passed to the component, fix it there and make sure its correctly parsed and it should work., Once we see the screenshot we might be able to help you parse it correctly.

Comment: Here's the real head scratcher...this .jsx file is a copy/paste from the Core MVC project where it works just fine. Parses exactly as expected.

Comment: Thats because the prop name in foo is different from the one you're passing to your compoent. `accountManager={foo.accountManager}` should be `accountManager={foo.AccountManager}` Notice the Capitalized names in console vs the camel case naes you're using., You have to use exact `property` names

Comment: AAAAAAARRRRRRGGGGGHHHHHHHH!!!!!! Yep, that was it.

Comment: Exactly., We all go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the screenshot you posted in **EDIT #2**

The issue is you're using **different property name** when accessing the data from `foo` while setting the properties on your component

So changing it from

```
<LineItem key={foo.ordHeaderId}
  accountManager={foo.accountManager}
  apptIconString={foo.apptIconString}
```

to

```
<LineItem key={foo.ordHeaderId}
  accountManager={foo.AccountManager}
...
```

should do the trick

That is use the **exact property name** from your **foo** object instead of using camel cased or some other version of it.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition in `<ItemList>` render is wrong. It should be like

`if(this.state.items.length > 0)`

Everything else looks fine. But, you forgot to add the `key` to the `<LineItem>` component

```
<LineItem key={foo.ordHeaderId}
 accountManager={foo.accountManager}
 ... />
```

Here, you are passing `key` as a `prop` to the `<LineItem>` component but you forgot to set that key from the prop to the parent element.

```
var LineItem = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="gridItem" key={this.props.key}>
            <div className="lessLineHeight smallFont">
        ....
     )
 }
})
```

This should remove the error/warning

Comment: I changed the test in the `if` statement to check the `length > 0` but that had no effect. In fact, it raised another error saying that `this.props.key` would result in being undefined. The first screenshot shows that I have items in state, so it's passing the > 0 test, it's just not hydrating the LineItem.

Comment: Try to do `console.log(this.props)` before the `return()` in `<LineItem>` and make sure you get all the props accordingly. There is high possibility that you're not parsing the response properly.

Comment: It doesn't look to be parsing anything, and nothing past the url and the pollInterval is making it into props. I'll post a screenshot to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have experienced you can't pass key as a prop element. Remove this from you LineItem and see if it works. Let the warning persist. You can figure out a way to remove the warning later if this works.

```
<LineItem 
        accountManager={foo.accountManager}
        apptIconString={foo.apptIconString}
        commodityDescription={foo.commodityDescription}
        commodityId={foo.commodityId}
        dateCreated={foo.dateCreated}
        deliveryAppt={foo.deliveryAppt}
        destContact={foo.destContact}
        destinationAddress={foo.destinationAddress}
        destinationAddressName={foo.destinationAddressName}
        destinationCity={foo.destinationCity}
        earlyDeliveryTime={foo.earlyDeliveryTime}
        earlyPickupTime={foo.earlyPickupTime}
        equipmentName={foo.equipmentName}
        freightValue={foo.freightValue}
        handlingUnits={foo.handlingUnits}
        hazmatIconString={foo.hazmatIconString}
        highValueIconString={foo.highValueIconString}
        isHazmat={foo.isHazmat}
        isHighValue={foo.isHighValue}
        lateDeliveryTime={foo.lateDeliveryTime}
        latePickupTime={foo.latePickupTime}
        loadId={foo.loadId}
        loadNum={foo.loadNum}
        loadTmsStatus={foo.loadTmsStatus}
        ordHeaderId={foo.ordHeaderId}
        ordNum={foo.ordNum}
        orderType={foo.orderType}
        origContact={foo.originContact}
        originAddress={foo.originAddress}
        originAddressName={foo.originAddressName}
        originationCity={foo.originationCity}
        pickupAppt={foo.pickupAppt}
        pieces={foo.pieces}
        plannedEnd={foo.plannedEnd}
        plannedStart={foo.plannedStart}
        requiredTemp={foo.requiredTemp}
        specialInstructions={foo.specialInstructions}
        targetCost={foo.targetCost}
        teamId={foo.teamId}
        tempControlled={foo.tempControlled}
        tradingPartnerNameCNum={foo.tradingPartnerNameCNum}
        tradingPartnerName={foo.tradingPartnerNameClient}
        transportMode={foo.transportMode}
        user3gIdBookedBy={foo.user3gIdBookedBy}
        user3gIdCreatedBy={foo.user3gIdCreatedBy}
        weight={foo.weight} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Random User found the answer and it's contained in his comment.

The "key" to the problem was not capitalizing the properties that were to be mapped. Not sure why it worked the way it was in Core MVC, but, obviously, it doesn't work the same in MVC 4.